# Git bash login "error: src refspec master does not match any"

Tags: git, bash

So, I'm trying the learn to basics of Git, but I'm having issues with logging in through Git Bash. I'm using Windows 7.

First I created a test repo in my Github account, than I tried to push it from the command line, like this:

```bash
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/martin-dzhonov/Test.git
$ git push -u origin master
```

Than I get prompted about username and password, and after entering them I get

```
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to https://github.com/martin-dzhonov/Test.git
```

Help ?

Comment: This is what I get with SSH:

Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: Did you upload your public key to GitHub? Have a look at [GitHub’s help page to SSH](https://help.github.com/categories/56/articles).

Comment: Just did. Still getting "error: src refspec master does not match any."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out I'm an idiot. I haven't changed the directory in the cmd so I was trying to push a non-existing repo.